# How to write an object of unknown type to a binary file?

Tags: c#, binary, binarywriter

Well this is basically like a generic binary writer... let's say you have an object, and you don't know what it is, but you have it. How do you write it's binary data to a binary file to be able to retrieve later?

My original idea that I don't know how to do was:

1. Figure out all the members of the object somehow (reflection maybe)
2. Unless the members are of types writable by the BinaryWriter, repeat step 1 on the member
3. Make a header that states the types of the members and how they are assembled into the object (somehow)
4. Write the header thing
5. Write all the core level members

I don't know how to use Reflection much so I'm not sure how to do most of the above.
It should be quite doable however.

How should I do this, if it's possible? Or how should I implement the above?

```
bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is to use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). However you should be very careful with any changes to your classes if you want to load instances saved by previous versions of your application.

Answer (score 1):

The hard aspect is not writing out objects, but reading them back.  The .NET framework provides various techniques for serialization and deserialization of class types which are supposed to automate the process, but all of the built-in techniques I'm familiar with have various limitations.

A major problem is that .NET makes no distinction between a storage location which holds a reference to an object for the purpose of *identifying* an object which is used by other code, for the purpose of only identifying *immutable* aspects of the object's state *other than identity*, or for the purpose of encapsulating the object's *mutable state*.  Without knowing what a field is supposed to represent, it's not possible to know how it should be serialized or deserialized.  For example, suppose that a particular type has a field of type `int[]`, which holds a reference to a single-element array which holds the value 23.  It may be that the purpose of that field is to hold the value 23, or it may be that the purpose of that field is to identify an array whose first element should be incremented every time something happens.  In the former scenario, serialization should write out the fact that it's a single element array containing the value 23.  In the latter scenario, if serialization is going to be possible at all, it will require knowing what is significant about the array to which the field holds a reference.

While various people have written various methods to automatically serialize various classes, I tend to be skeptical of such things.  If one doesn't know what the fields of a class are used for, one should be cautious making any assumptions about what state is encapsulated thereby.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible with [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). But think of an object structure where you have many of your `unknown` objects which all reference a common object. If you serialize all of your `unknown` objects you end up with as many copies of the common object as there are `unknown` objects.

And there might be many fields of the `unknown` object which are not relevant as they are set by the constructor or other classes, they could be in an inconsistent state when deserialized.

So it might be not so hard to serialize them, but how do you want to deserialize them?